perfmon - recognize devices luids
I've retrieved shared VRAM memory from perfmon counters using Get-Counter -Counter '\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Shared Usage':
Timestamp                 CounterSamples
---------                 --------------
11.08.2024 00:02:25       \\pc\gpu adapter memory(luid_0x00000000_0x00013245_phys_0)\shared usage :
                          1200861184

                          \\pc\gpu adapter memory(luid_0x00000000_0x00013658_phys_0)\shared usage :
                          8192

                          \\pc\gpu adapter memory(luid_0x00000000_0x0001368a_phys_0)\shared usage :
                          262144

By looking at the values I can guess that the third one is NVidia videocard, the first one - Intel integrated videocard and the second one - no idea what is.
What would be the proper way to make sense of those luid values like luid_0x00000000_0x00013245_phys_0 - where I can find some description what device they're referring to exactly?

I suspect that the 8192 might be a basic display adapter used by the system before the proper driver is loaded. I have a similar device with the same number on my system which has no integrated graphics.
